# phoenix framework render json view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have action in `user_controller`:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Api.V2.UserController do
    use MyAppWeb, :controller
    plug MyAppWeb.Plugs.Auth
    action_fallback MyAppWeb.FallbackController

    def show(conn, _) do
        conn
        |> put_status(:ok)
        |> render(MyAppWeb.Api.V2.UserView, "user.json", user: conn.assigns.current_user)
    end

end
```

and `user_view.ex`:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Api.V2.UserView do
    use MyAppWeb, :view
    alias MyAppWeb.Api.V2.UserView
    require Logger

    def render("show.json", %{user: user}) do
        %{data: render_one(user, UserView, "user.json")}
    end

    def render("user.json", %{user: user, session: session}) do
        Logger.warn "here"
        Logger.warn inspect(session)
        %{
            token: session.token,
            credits: MyApp.Account.get_user_balance(user)
        }
    end

    def render("user.json", %{user: user}) do
        %{
            credits: MyApp.Account.get_user_balance(user)
        }
    end

end
```

The problem is that the result of the query renders `render("user.json", %{user: user, session: session})` instead of `render("user.json", %{user: user})`:

```
15:06:25.157 request_id=034c7f0sjbglmb0ocl1f1rehe6b0tjrv [warn] here
15:06:25.163 request_id=034c7f0sjbglmb0ocl1f1rehe6b0tjrv [warn] %MyApp.Sessions.Session{...}
15:06:25.176 request_id=034c7f0sjbglmb0ocl1f1rehe6b0tjrv [warn] %{"credits" => %{...}, "token" => "7Zo...Eu"}
```

why is this happening?

because I do not pass the session to view.

Phoenix version 1.3.0, Elixir version 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly stated in [`Phoenix.Controller.render/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/3) documentation, the `assigns` from the controller are merged with the connection assigns (`conn.assigns`):

> • `assigns` — a dictionary with the assigns to be used in the view. Those assigns are merged and have higher precedence than the connection assigns (`conn.assigns`)

To hijack the default behaviour, one might explicitly pass `session: nil` to `render` since it has a higher precedence than the connection assigns.